# How to overlap curves

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

With the curve in edit mode i have deleted & with the draw tool, I have created some infinity shape. With the tolerance 3, Why the curve not overlapping curve on each other.

[image]

[I tried this way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v83mr.jpg)

Im looking to model this type of folded wire / cable.

[image]

Any other way which i can create in quick way, other than mine, plz do mention. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to manually move the curves over each other so that they give the *appearance* of overlapping. Curves in Blender do not automatically overlap, so you must do this yourself.

Simply move the curves over each other in edit mode until you get the desired result.

Setting tolerance does not automatically overlap the curves.